# Ordinary Least Squares Derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I have been trying to follow the derivation of the normal equations, but there is one part I do not understand.

So, if we minimize

$L(\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}-(2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{X})\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b}^T(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})\mathbf{b}$

then $\frac{\delta L(\mathbf{b})}{\delta \mathbf{b}}= \mathbf{0}-2\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}+2(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})\mathbf{b}$

I would have thought $(2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{X})\mathbf{b}$ simply becomes $(2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{X})$. But apparently it does not, and I cannot find the full derivation anywhere. I'd be very grateful for an explanation.

Comment: Your second term is a matrix times a column vector, so it produces a column vector. So the first must be of the same kind. You cannot have a row vector + a column vector.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDoe, that explains a lot. So I take it I could also transpose the second term and leave the first one as is?

Comment: Yes exactly $\uparrow$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of writing it - in either way you must make sure you are consistent with where the index of your derivative goes.$$\frac{dL}{db_p}=\frac{d}{db_p}\left( y_jy_j-2y_iX_{ij}b_j+b_i X_{ki}X_{kj}b_j \right)=0-2y_iX_{ip}+X_{kp}X_{kj}b_j+b_iX_{ki}X_{kp}\\=-2y_iX_{ip}+2X_{ki}X_{kp}b_i$$This can be written in one of two ways: $\left[-2y^TX+2b^TX^TX \right]_p$ or $\left[-2X^Ty+2X^TXb \right]_p$. The former is in the form of a row vector, the latter is a column vector. You probably want your answer to be a column vector, so you go for
$$\frac{dL}{d\vec b}=-2X^T\vec y+2X^TX\vec b$$

Answer (score 0):

(Since everything I'm gong to talk about would be bold, I'm not going to bother.)

Did you try the $2 \times 2$ version to get some insight?
$$ y = \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}, X = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22}\end{pmatrix}  \text{.}  $$
So,
$$2 X^T y = \begin{pmatrix}2x_{11}y_1 + 2x_{21}y_2 \\ 2x_{12}y_1 + 2x_{22}y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$2 y^T X = \begin{pmatrix}2x_{11}y_1 + 2x_{21}y_2 & 2x_{12}y_1 + 2x_{22}y_2 \end{pmatrix}  \text{.}$$
They're the same thing, up to transposition.

Comment: @JohnDoe : Yeah.  Typo'ed the separator, then described what I was looking at.  Since fixed.

Comment: While they are the same thing, you cannot use the row vector version in the equation the OP gives, since the thing we add it to is a column vector - it must be one or the other. See my answer and comment on the original question. Alternatively, if we want to find $dL/dB$ as a row vector, then we _would_ be able to use the row vector here, but then the $X^TXb$ term would have to be transposed.

Comment: @JohnDoe : I had considered adding this, but it is already covered in the comments to the Question.