# Derivative transpose (follow up)

Tags: matrices, derivatives, linear-regression, transpose

I'm working through the Elements of Statistical learning, and I have a quick followup to the below question:

[derivative transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850034/derivative-transpose)

In the answer accepted, it states the below: 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(\beta^T X^TX\beta) = 2X^TX\beta
$$

For context, $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, and $\beta$ is a $p \times 1$ matrix.

I'm a bit confused about that. When I do the product rule, I see the below:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(\beta^T X^TX\beta) = (\beta^TX^T)'(X\beta)+(\beta^TX^T)(X\beta)' = X^TX\beta+ \beta^TX^TX
$$

My issue now is that $X^TX\beta$ is a $p\times 1$ matrix, and $\beta^TX^TX$ is a $1\times p$ matrix. I mean, I guess it doesn't matter since they're both vectors and each other's transposes, but this seems shaky from a dimensionality perspective. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of why it is a bad idea to differentiate with respect to vectors! Do it componentwise and you get the following. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_p}(\beta_iX_{ki} X_{kj}\beta_j)=X_{kp}X_{kj}\beta_j+\beta_iX_{ki}X_{kp}=(2X^TX\beta)_p$$It is conventional for the derivative of a scalar with respect to a *column* vector to be a *column* vector, so we must have that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(\beta^TX^TX\beta)=2X^TX\beta$$Note that $(2X^TX\beta)_p=(2\beta^TX^TX)_p$, so if we wanted our derivative to be a row vector, this would also be true.

---

See also: [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2730993/399334) of mine to a very similar question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about a few things. First, why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_p} (\beta_i X_{ki}) = X_{kp}$ (or similarly for the j term)? Second, why does $X_{kp} X_{kj}\beta_{j} + \beta_i X_{ki} X_{kp} = 2X^T X \beta$?

Comment: To answer your first question, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_p}(\beta_iX_{ki})=\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_p}(\beta_i)X_{ki}\\=\delta_{pi}X_{ki}=X_{kp}$$Note, I am using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and $\delta$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: To answer your second question, $$X_{kp}X_{kj}\beta_j=(X^T)_{pk}X_{kj}\beta_j=[X^TX\beta]_p\\
\beta_iX_{ki}X_{kp}=(X^T)_{pk}X_{ki}\beta_i=[X^TX\beta]_p$$So the sum of these two is $[2X^TX\beta]_p$

Comment: Thank you for that explanation (and for pre-empting a question with those links)! Einstein summation always gave me a headache.

Comment: Er, one last thing if you don't mind humoring me. To get $\beta_i K_{ki} X_{kp} = (X^T)_{pk} X_{ki} \beta_i$, is it just because everything is scalar and dandy and you get commutativity for free?

Comment: @deetsb I am not sure what you mean by double transpose, so I will simply explain that step. Firstly remember that all three of these objects we have are _components_ of a vector or a matrix, so they themselves are scalars. This means that we can swap the order of multiplication since this is okay for scalars (as you said, we get commutativity for free). So $\beta_iX_{ki}X_{kp}=X_{kp}X_{ki}\beta_i$. Then we use the fact that the $a,b$ component of a matrix is equal to the $b,a$ component of its transpose. So $X_{kp}=(X^T)_{pk}$. Therefore we get $$\beta_iX_{ki}X_{kp}=(X^T)_{pk} X_{ki}\beta_i$$

Comment: Funnily enough, I just realized they were all scalars after I'd put that question, and edited my question to reflect that. Think I might have done it while you were answering -- my apologies. Thanks for confirming, I'd totally over thought it. By double transpose, I meant doing something like $AB = ((AB)^T)^T$ and then trying to "work it out" from there. Completely forgot we were in scalar world so all this stuff wasn't necessary.

Comment: Ahh yes, I noticed. Manipulating components and standard suffix notation stuff is often very confusing near the start - I've had people ask very similar questions to this before, so I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(\beta)=\beta^TX^TX\beta$. You want to compute $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \beta}$. This can be found by considering a small $p\times 1$ vector $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e$ and looking at
$$
F(\beta+\e)-F(\beta)=\e^TX^TX\beta+\beta^TX^TX\e +\require{cancel}\cancelto{o(\|\e\|)}{\e^TX^TX\e}\approx\e^TX^TX\beta+\beta^TX^TX\e=2\e^TX^TX\beta
$$
The last equality follows since $\beta^TX^TX\e$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, and therefore equal to its transpose.

This shows that the difference $F(\beta+\e)-F(\beta)$ is well approximated by $\epsilon^T$ times $2X^TX\beta$, so that $2X^TX\beta$ is the derivative of $F$.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the answer. I've never thought of it this way, but if you don't mind clarifying something, why does $\epsilon^T X^T X \epsilon$ converge to zero as the norm of $\epsilon$ approaches 0?

Comment: @deetsb that is because it is $o(\|\epsilon\|)$, so as $\|\epsilon\|\to0$, this term goes to $0$ fast than $\|\epsilon\|$.

Comment: Oh it's little o notation. Thank you, haven't seen that for a bit.